# best way to implement dynamical tableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview

On image you can see screen, that I need to implement

http://cs301703.userapi.com/u20441799/154158276/z_aadbf840.jpg

I'm confused with dynamic table cell height size because movie title and description might be various. Is there something in iOS like LinarLayout in Android, where I can put elements and layout would be resized?

Is it better to use custom xib for TableView Cell with all needed views(imageview, labels, etc) or programatically add views to TableView Cell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your design I would suggest that you should keep the Cell height uniform rather than changing it for different entries. What should change instead is the label height/width and font size/weight to cater for each films' title.

If you have lots of cells in the table you will get performance benefits from keeping uniform cell height and also if you re-use the cells then it will be better for you if they are uniform.

Re: XIB / Programatic

Doing this kind of thing in a XIB can be quite frustrating but once you get past the following sticking point it really is best.

Sticky Point: You do not use File's Owner (Under Placeholders) to link to your IBOutlets - instead you use the cell itself (Under Objects).

You also have to ensure that the Cell Object is connected to the correct class (in the Identity Inspector).

Once you have got your subclassed cell using IOBOutlets from a nib this kind of work can be a joy.

Programatically this can be done in a straightforward manner by simply adding subviews to whichever kind of cell you create. You won't have the issues highlighted above BUT in a busy cell you will end up with a great deal of code inside **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** which is not quite desirable.

[image: Crappy Highlighting of IBOutlet connecting]

Comment: Thanks for detailed response! I'll try with xib

Answer (score 1):

Both XIB and programmatically are fine.

To adjust the height of your cell, calculate the necessary height and return it in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` of your table view controller. You will have to return a proper height for each row.

Comment: Ok, but how can I move down movie description label if movie title label becomes bigger (in height)? Do I need to calculate the height of title label and then offset description label?

Comment: Yes, you will have to adjust the size and position of these elements dynamically. This is done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the part where you customize the cell.