# How to set the height of subviews of UItableViewCell when cell is created programaticalliy

Tags: iphone, ios

I have custom cell created with nib. In the table view I am using the method `-(float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to set the height of cell
Everything works fine. 
 But the problem is that I also want to change the size of UIlabel which is added as subview in nib of cell.
How do I do that?
Which metod to override in customcell class ?

Comment: Can you please include the code of cellForRowAtIndexPath function

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubview];
   //Do your magic 
}
```

layoutSubviews is call after the cell is created and whenever the device orientation changes, to allow you to resize and/or move the subviews (plus make any other minor adjustments) to compensate for differences between the orientations, but in this case you can also use it to redraw your subviews.

Answer (score 0):

As you have UILabel in your custom cell class, make a function in that class that take frame you want to set as parameter. Set frame of label in that function. You need to call this function from your cellForRowAtIndexPath method before returning the cell.

If you are reusing your custom cell you should call method only when the (cell == nil)
Also if you can add some code in your question that would be helpful and you can get more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat your custom cell in the same way you would treat a normal view or view controller class with a xib. i.e. You need to create IBOutlets for the controls in you custom cell and during creation of the cell you can access the controls quite easily.

```
myCell.myCustomUILabel.text = @"blah"
```

There are some gotchas when using custom cells in a xib and onnecting up the IBOutlets. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9615616/741626) SO answer (of mine) explains how to create and link up IBOutlets of a custom cell.